# What happens if the fielder fails to walk in from outside the boundary ropes when the ball is delivered?

Tags: rules, cricket, cricket-world-cup

During the time of delivery, if a fielder fielding near the boundary line fails to come into the ground will it be called a NO Ball?

Answer (score 2):

No. The reasons for a no ball are listed in [Law 24](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-24-no-ball/) (and the subsidiary bits mentioned in Law 24.9) and do not include "fielder not in the field of play".

In theory, Law 2, Section 6 says that:

> If a player comes on to the field of play *[without permission of the umpires]* and comes into contact with the ball while it is in play,
>
> (a) the ball shall immediately become dead and the umpire shall award 5 penalty runs to the batting side.

However, it's clearly not the intent of this law to be applied to players who were signing autographs at the boundary between balls, even if they didn't quite make it back onto the field by the time the ball was bowled.

So I think the simple answer here is: nothing happens.

Comment: It is a Philip says, 5 penalty runs when the player touches the ball.  As a matter of course for umpires we would keep an eye on players near the boundary and remind them if needed.  However if a player had left the field say for a toilet break and returned without permission the 5 runs would be applied.